# Проверка правильности отображения сайта в интернет эксплорере если у меня МАС

Tags: macos, internet-explorer

Как проверить как будет выглядеть мой сайт в браузере интернет эксплорере если у меня МАК? 
Ответы а ля купи или поставь винду не принимаются)

Answer (score 1):

ставь форточки на vmware fusion, parallels desktop или virtual box и тестируй наздоровье.

Answer (score 0):

[www.browserstack.com](http://browserstack.com)

Answer (score 0):

Можно делать скрины сайта на http://browsershots.org/, правда, работает довольно медленно и ограниченное количество скринов в сутки.
Еще есть https://browserling.com/, но на счет его работы ничего сказать не могу.